# how to drop table with conditions upon oracle?

Tags: oracle

just like this:

```
drop table  xxxx where table_name like 'v_%';
```

I can retrieve the table names form the database,but i don't know how do it with a simply way.
tables from:

```
select table_name from user_tables wher table_name like 'v_%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PL/SQL code you can do it like this:

```
set serveroutput on;

begin
    for table_record in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'v_%')
    loop
        execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || table_record.table_name ;
        dbms_output.put_line('Table ' ||  table_record.table_name  || ' dropped' );
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: your r better than i'v tried;

DECLARE
CURSOR tabs IS
select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'V_%';
BEGIN
    FOR tab IN tabs LOOP
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || tab.table_name;
        END;
    END LOOP; 
END;

Answer (score 0):

Example sql code to generate a script to delete tables or other objects (indexes, packages).
This example is safer, because Allows you to view the list for deletion before deleting objects.

```
  select 'drop '|| object_type||' '||owner||'.'||object_name||' cascade constraints ;'
    from all_objects
    where owner='ASUZM'
    and object_type in ('TABLE')
    and object_name like 'V%'
    order by object_type;
```

Comment: Answers with only code and no comments or explanation are generally viewed as "low quality" and subject to deletion.

Comment: "The script will need to be run several times".  Or we could just use `cascade constraint` as in my answer [in the marked duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7568520/146325)